# Private networking beetween many servers

Tags: linux, networking

I'm looking for solution who allow contacting beetwen vm's in private networking in multiple servers/datacenters. I mind to do tunnel GRE beetwen servers and split as private network subnets, software solution is only possible because network will be based in OVH and Hetzner.

[image]

Comment: What exactly is your question? What did you try so far?

Comment: I tested only GRE/IPIP tunnel between two servers, i'm looking good tips about this to skip problems in future.

Comment: your answer is in your own question ... make subnets from a software rooter with subnets  ; it can be a virtual machine on one of your existing nodes  or adding a host dedicated to that  //  softrouter for examples : IPCop -- smoothwall -- DD-WRT -- Tomato etc... etc... you will choose

Comment: In our company we use zerotier. Not sure it fits the bill but it works for us.